# Get the value after group by in gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

```
g.V('JobDefinition1').out("JobDefinitionToJobHistory").has("Timestamp", between("2022-02-01T00:00:00Z", "2022-02-03T00:00:00Z")).group().by("ttl").by(limit(1))
```

I had a gremlin query above and get the result below.

```
[
  {
    "776": [
      {
        "id": "JobHistory-2-1-2022 12:19:15 AM",
        "label": "JobHistory",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "Timestamp": [
            {
              "id": "6d187ccf-160d-4d87-a360-48526b7a1461",
              "value": "2022-02-01T00:00:00Z"
            }
          ],
          "ttl": [
            {
              "id": "JobHistory-2-1-2022 12:19:15 AM|ttl",
              "value": "776"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "888": [
      {
        "id": "JobHistory-2-1-2022 12:19:15 AM",
        "label": "JobHistory",
        "type": "vertex",
        "properties": {
          "Timestamp": [
            {
              "id": "6d187ccf-160d-4d87-a360-48526b7a1461",
              "value": "2022-02-01T00:00:00Z"
            }
          ],
          "ttl": [
            {
              "id": "JobHistory-2-1-2022 12:19:15 AM|ttl",
              "value": "888"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I want to only get the value of the result after group by, the excepted result is shown below. I want the groupby result value without the key(as you can see, the excepted result don't have key info such as "776" and "888"). Is there any gremlin method to help me achieve this goal. Hope you can give me some help. Thanks!

```
[
  {
    "id": "JobHistory-2-1-2022 12:19:15 AM",
    "label": "JobHistory",
    "type": "vertex",
    "properties": {
      "Timestamp": [
        {
          "id": "6d187ccf-160d-4d87-a360-48526b7a1461",
          "value": "2022-02-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
      ],
      "ttl": [
        {
          "id": "JobHistory-2-1-2022 12:19:15 AM|ttl",
          "value": "776"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ,
  {
    "id": "JobHistory-2-1-2022 12:19:15 AM",
    "label": "JobHistory",
    "type": "vertex",
    "properties": {
      "Timestamp": [
        {
          "id": "6d187ccf-160d-4d87-a360-48526b7a1461",
          "value": "2022-02-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
      ],
      "ttl": [
        {
          "id": "JobHistory-2-1-2022 12:19:15 AM|ttl",
          "value": "888"
        }
      ]
    }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get values from a `Map` with `select(values)`:

```
gremlin> g.V().groupCount().by(label)
==>[software:2,person:4]
gremlin> g.V().groupCount().by(label).select(values)
==>[2,4]
```